# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, web, netbeans

I just started to learn spring boot. I only coded a simple hello world program but whatever i try i can't fix this problem.

**There is my pom file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Here is the log:**

```
cd C:\Users\sedat\Documents\NetBeansProjects\InitializrSpringbootProject; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.2" cmd /c "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-14\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.vmArgs= \"-Dexec.args=${exec.vmArgs} -classpath %classpath ${exec.mainClass} ${exec.appArgs}\" \"-Dexec.executable=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.2\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.demo.DemoApplication -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dexec.appArgs= \"-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-14\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec"
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

--------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ demo ---
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.example.demo.DemoApplication
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/demo/DemoApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 58.0
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  0.853 s
Finished at: 2022-12-08T16:29:21+03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project demo: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I've tried to add main class and some plugins to the pom file but none of them seem to worked. And i changed the java version on pom but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please provide logs from your executions.

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski sorry about that, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is java version. You are using Java 8 with Spring Boot 3.0.0 and that is incorrect because Spring Boot 3.0.0 only supports Java 17. So there are two ways to fix the problem.

1. Upgrade Java version from 8 to 17 and try again.
2. Use old version of Spring Boot i.e 2.7.6 and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. First way seems to work.